# Unable to run a powershell script in command prompt

Tags: powershell

i have an issue where when i try to run an email powershell script in command prompt not working. But if i run the script in powershell it works and send an email to my outlook account but if trying to run the script in the command prompt it opens the powershell window but no email was sent. Please help me with this issue

```
Start-Process powershell.exe "$env:C:\wifi.ps1
```

i tried running the script manually in windows powershell it works

Comment: [Edit] the question and show exactly how you are trying to run the Powershell script from command prompt.

Comment: I doubt **PowerShell** can find your script. `$env:C:\wifi.ps1` ?!?!?  Are you trying to reference an environmental varaible in the path?

Comment: `Start-Process` won't be recognized as a command in cmd.exe. and again, `$env:C:\wifi.ps1` makes no sense as a path.